# How to set background color with opacity by css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, opacity

1. I'm trying to set the background menu color (drop down) like this site:
   http://www.artofplacement.com/wordpress/
   But I can't pick the color code. Its blue but less opacity I guess. How can I set background color with less opacity such as the reference site dropdown menu?
   I just want to copy the same menu css from
   http://www.artofplacement.com/wordpress/ to my site. I will put my working site in comments.

But I can't copy the background color from the dropdown menu.

1. Check this site: artofplacement.com/wordpress, when you mouse in to Room, you see a red bg color and a dropdown list and note that, the red bg is sticky until you mouse out to other menu. I need this sticky red. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is my working site:http://www.artofplacement.com/avada/

Comment: `background: rgba(163,192,246,0.6);`

Comment: It works fine. But the code given by J.K is better. Thanks@mdesdev

Comment: Check this site: http://www.artofplacement.com/wordpress/, when you mouse in to Room, you see a red bg color and a dropdown list and note that, the red bg is sticky until you mouse out to other menu. I need this sticky red. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this color i exactly match with that sample site...
change your font color as you like.
background-color: rgba(164, 191, 246, 0.6);
or
background: rgba(164, 191, 246, 0.6);
or
color: rgba(164, 191, 246, 0.6);

Comment: Can you help me to set active background color to the main menu when a dropwoen list is shown? Just check the sample site. Now its shown but immediately goes after mouse out to the dropdown list. I need that hover color sticky until I mouse out to other menu. Thanks.

Comment: Check this site: http://www.artofplacement.com/wordpress/, when you mouse in to Room, you see a red bg color and a dropdown list and note that, the red bg is sticky until you mouse out to other menu. I need this sticky red. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Ad your drop down menu css hover effect :

```
background-image: rgba(235,235,235,1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#a60000 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#a60000 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#a60000 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#a60000 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#a60000 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

Working demo: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/zGImr)
Another Demo: [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/Lfud5/)

Comment: I'm looking the code for plain color. You suggested background-image, why not background-color? Thanks @Cosmos

Comment: Because of the gradient in your example have the ability to hover in effect

Comment: I'm looking the code for the dropdown menu bg code, not the menu hover code. Thanks@Cosmos